# How to define an alias in Agda's type delaration?

Tags: functional-programming, agda

My code:

```
law : ∀ a x → ((suc a) * (suc a) ÷ (suc a) ⟨ x ⟩) →ℕ ≡ (suc a , refl)
law a x = refl
```

I think there's too many `suc a` and I want to give an alias to `suc a`, something like (this code just describes my idea, it doesn't compile):

```
law : ∀ a x → ((s : suc a) * s ÷ s ⟨ x ⟩) →ℕ ≡ (s , refl)
law a x = refl
```

Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. You can use `let`

```
law : ∀ a x → let s = suc a in (s * s ÷ s ⟨ x ⟩) →ℕ ≡ (s , refl)
law a x = refl
```

or define an anonymous module:

```
module _ (a : ℕ) where
  s = suc a
  law : ∀ x → (s * s ÷ s ⟨ x ⟩) →ℕ ≡ (s , refl)
  law x = refl
```

Outside of the module `law` has the same type signature as the one you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!